# Question related to optimization of nature $\text{min} ~~ Q(x) ~~ \text{subjected to} ~~C(x, y) \geq C_0$

Tags: optimization

This is little off-the-track question than the conventional ones asked in this forum. This is a problem related to my research. I am stuck to an optimization problem of the following nature:

$\text{min} ~~ Q(x) ~~ \text{subjected to} ~~C(x, y) \geq C_0$, where $y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

I have thought of the approach is to integrate out the $y$ from $C(x, y)$ and make it a function of $x, \mu$ and $\sigma^2$ like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} C(x, y) \mathcal{N}(y; \mu, \sigma^2) dy$. Is this approach mathematically correct? What problems can come on the value $C_0$?

All the functions, $Q(x)$, $C(x, y)$ are exponential in nature and contains $\text{erf}$ functions as components.

Please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we trying to satisfy the constraint with some probability $p$, or must it be always satisfied? If always, why not take $y^*$ to be the $y$ which minimizes $C$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Yes that can be a possibility to fix $y$ at $y^*$ and get different values of $C(x,y)$. A range of values of $y$ can be chosen. But the problem in my case is $x \in \mathbb{R}^{33}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{33}$ also. So, a prohibitively large number of $y$ values will be required which will require a prohibitively large number of evaluation of $C(x,y)$. Thats why I wanted to have a closed form expression of $C(x,y)$. And for the first question, the constraint must always be satisfied. Moreover, the $C(x,y)$ has a closed form expression.

Answer (score 3):

Because $y$ is random, you have to specify in what manner you want the constraint to hold.

Your "integrating out" thought apparently corresponds to having the constraint satisfied in expectation, i.e., $E(C(x,y)) \ge 0$.  This renders the optimization problem a deterministic optimization problem.

An alternative possibility would be to specify that the constraint is satisfied with some minimum probability. i.e, $P(C(x,y) \ge C_0) \ge p$, where $p$ is part of the specification of the optimization problem. This is known as a chance constraint, making your optimization problem a "chance-constrained program", for which there is a large literature. This is a type of stochastic optimization (programming) problem. See for example https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/chance_constr.pdf .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. The constraint is deterministic in nature and I have derived a closed form expression based upon the distribution of $x$. Moreover for the second question the constraint must be satisfied every time. The type of constraint (chance constraint) you have written is extensively used in reliability based design optimization (RBDO). I think if I keep the value of $p$ at $0.999$ then also it will be a kind of deterministic optimization.

Comment: You said that y has a distribution.  x is the optimization (decision) variable, so doesn't have a distribution.  Given that y is Normally distributed, it seems possible that there will be no value of x for which the constraint can be satisfied with probability 1; in such case, you'll have to decide on an acceptable value p.  If you take the integrating out approach, the probability that the constraint is satisfied at the optimal x will presumably be less than 1, unless your constraint winds up being trivial.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. If $x$ is a decision variable then can it not have a distribution? I mean can a decision variable not be a random variable? Second thing is, suppose $x$  and $y$ both are deterministic variables then is there any optimization procedure for this type of problem? Because, the objective does not have the other set of variable $y$.

Comment: If x is a scalar, vector or matrix variable, etc. then it would not be random.  you would find an optimal value. If your problem was to choose a distribution, for instance, an optimal parameter value of a distribution, then the x would still be deterministic, but it's possible your objective function could be stochastic (random). If x and y are deterministic, then it's a deterministic optimization problem. But in such case, y would not have a (non-zero variance) Normal distribution. If you tell us explicitly what Q and C are, something more concrete can be said about your problem.

Comment: In particular, I am having this problem in robust design of parameters and tolerances in quality design. $x$ are tolerance variables and $y$ are parameter variables i.e. any system parameter can be described as $y \pm 3x$. The objective function is cost of assigning tolerances $x$ and the cost does not depend on parameter $y$ values. But in constraint we have to satisfy the quality yield which is a function of both parameter and tolerance values. Now in robust design the objective is to find the parameter values which will be least sensitive to both external and internal errors.

Comment: You need to clarify in what manner the quality yield needs to be satisfied.  And if you don't know for sure that y is Normally distributed, and with the mean and variance you have stated, you may wish to consider a robust optimization variant of chance-constrained programming, in which you try to make the solution robust against differences of y from the distribution you have stated.

Comment: Regarding quality yield, it must be satisfied all the time. So, you mean to say that I can use a global robust optimization type of the form $\text{min}_{x\in X} {f(x); g(x, y) \leq b, \forall y \in Y }$ if no information regarding the variables $x,y$ are available.

Comment: There is no "information" about x, it is a decision variable, i.e., you, in consultation with your optimizer, choose it. As for y, you have to assume something, but there is some choice in the formulation of your problem as to what that is. I think you need to do some reading on robust and stochastic optimization in order to structure your thinking.  I don't think you're going to get where you need from answers on this board.

Comment: Can you cite me some source where I can get this type of optimization problem i.e. $\min f(x) s.t. C(x,y) > C_0 \forall y $? Is the global robust optimization term is OK for searching? and does Prof Ben-Tal's book on robust optimization cover this type of problem? Cite me some source I will start reading... Any particular algorithm which is used to solve this? BTW, both objective and constraint are nonlinear in nature. Thanks a lot for sparing time for me.

Comment: Ben-tal et all book deals with conic (convex) optimization, which apparently yours is not, but it may help structure/frame your thinking.  If you have nonlinear non-convex functions, then your problem is difficult.  You can search on global robust optimization and other variants. Also, nonlinear chance constrained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fruitful discussion. I will pay attention on your advice. Thanks again...